# How to use [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:url]?

Tags: ios, photo, alassetslibrary, chunks, nsfilehandle

I want to pass  assets URL

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=1000000001&ext=PNG"];
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:url]
NSLog(@"fileHandle: %@", fileHandle);
```

I am getting

```
fileHandle = nil;
```

How I can create fileHandle object from assets URL please let me know

Becuase I want to upload the file in chunk.

Comment: Thanks Dharmesh,
So is there any right way to create NSFileHandle Object from ALAssets.

Comment: Looks like we cannot read ALAsset URL using NSFileHandler. Did you find any way?